# Where can I found Services creation in JBPM

Tags: jbpm

How do I integrate other applications into my application using service task in JBPM?.Really appreciated if any one shared the code for that in JBPM.

Comment: Please add more details

Answer (score 0):

I suppose a custom work handler is what you looking for. You can find the tutorial on how to create one [here](http://fxapps.blogspot.my/2015/04/creating-custom-work-item-handler-in.html).

I hope it will give you some idea on how to apply it to your scenario.

Comment: Please let us know if you get to the answer using this solution to help others in finding the correct answer. Thanks.